# Entropy of single electron in hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

Ignoring the angular momentum and spin states, the states of an electron in a hydrogen atom consist of the energy eigenstates $|\psi_n \rangle$ with quantum number $n$. Since there are (countably) infinitely many of such states $\Omega$ the electron can occupy, does this mean its entropy is infinite? Or does "the entropy" of this single electron not have physical meaning? Thanks!

Comment: With what probability does the electron occupy each of these states? All you've stated is that the maximum entropy is infinite, which isn't saying much.

Answer (score 2):

As in the comments, you need to specify the probability distribution for the electron eigenstates. This distribution can depend on the hydrogen atom's environment - if the hydrogen atom is in a resonant cavity filled with radiation, then the probability that the electron will be found in its higher energy eigenstates is different from when the hydrogen atom is cooled to a few microkelvins.

Given the probability distribution $p_i$ for the probability to find the electron in the $i^{th}$ energy eigenstate, the Shannon entropy of the electron in bits is:

$$S = - \sum\limits_i p_i\,\log_2 p_i$$

Comment: The subtlety of this problem is that there is a pileup of states when approaching the continuum, and an uncountable (in the technical mathematical sense) number of continuum states.  The partition function will diverge unless you apply a cutoff related to the volume per atom.

Comment: @BertBarrois The appropriate pdfs, like the MB distribution will do this. Also the sum is kind of an abstraction - when we consider unbound states, the sum becomes an integral and the appropriate measure, depending on the physical conditions modelled,  will render the integral convergent. But i sense we may be saying the same thing in different words.